# Trying to transfer data from one jFrame to another jFrame with the help of a Java Class

Tags: java, encapsulation

I am trying to transfer a email and password data taken in one jFrame to another using a separate java Class. ***All are in same Package***. Any help is much appreciated, this is my first question so don't know the proper specifics to mention so let me know if you require.

**LoginForm.java** (1st jFrame)

*Part where the data manipulation is present* here **String mail,pass;** have email and password data

```
    if(op==true) {
                 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login Successful!", "WebApp Database Login",
                 INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                 DataTransfer dt=new DataTransfer();      // Setting instance of DataTransfer class 
                                                            //to pass on Mail and Password details
                 dt.setEmail(mail);
                 dt.setPassword(pass);
                 InfoDisplay id=new InfoDisplay();
                 id.setVisible(true);
                 }
```

**DataTransfer.java**

```
    public class DataTransfer {
        private String loginEmail;
        private String loginPassword;

        public String getEmail() {
            return loginEmail;
        }
    
        public String getPassword() {
            return loginPassword;
        }
    
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            loginEmail=email;
            System.out.println("Stored Mail: "+loginEmail);
        }
    
        public void setPassword(String password) {
            loginPassword=password;
            System.out.println("Stored Pass: "+loginPassword);
        } }
```

**InfoDisplay.java** (2nd jFrame)

//Constructor

```
    public InfoDisplay() {
        initComponents();
        //Displaying Current Date and Time
        Calendar cl=Calendar.getInstance();
        String datetime=cl.getTime().toString();
        jLabel5.setText(datetime);
        //Getting the Stored details of Mail and Password from DataTransfer class
        DataTransfer dt=new DataTransfer();
        String finalEmail=dt.getEmail();
        String finalPass=dt.getPassword();
        System.out.println("Email: "+finalMail);
        System.out.println("Password: "+finalPass); }
```

I have used Print commands to just check whether they are assigned properly or not. I am running the program from only **LoginForm.java**, and the data gets stored in **DataTransfer.java** but it shows **Email:** *NULL* and **Password:** *NULL* values in **InfoDisplay()**

Comment: Do not construct new `DataTransfer` in `InfoDisplay`. You need to share a reference to the same `DataTransfer` instance between `LoginForm` and  `InfoDisplay`. You can do so by `InfoDisplay id=new InfoDisplay(dt)`.

Comment: @c0der Wow thank you for the help. I was confused at first by now it clear that making new Instance was what went wrong since the new instance basically considers it as a new reference right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with this....

**LoginForm.java**

```
public class LoginForm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DataTransfer dataTransfer = new DataTransfer();
        dataTransfer.setEmail(mail);
        dataTransfer.setPassword(pass);
        InfoDdisplay infoDdisplay = new InfoDdisplay(dataTransfer);
    }
}
```

**InfoDisplay.java**

```
public class InfoDisplay {
    public InfoDisplay(DataTransfer dt) {
        //Displaying Current Date and Time
        //Getting the Stored details of Mail and Password from DataTransfer class
        String finalEmail = dt.getEmail();
        String finalPass = dt.getPassword();
        System.out.println("Email: " + finalEmail);
        System.out.println("Password: " + finalPass);
    }
}
```

**DataTransfer.java**

```
public class DataTransfer {
    private String loginEmail;
    private String loginPassword;

    public String getEmail() {
        return loginEmail;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return loginPassword;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        loginEmail=email;
        System.out.println("Stored Mail: "+loginEmail);
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        loginPassword=password;
        System.out.println("Stored Pass: "+loginPassword);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Wow, that worked :) Thanks now I got what went from. I think making new instance again in InfoDisplay() was my mistake.

Comment: You can change `InfoDdisplay infoDdisplay = new InfoDdisplay(dataTransfer);` to `new InfoDdisplay(dataTransfer);` because `infoDdisplay` is never used.

Comment: @c0der Yes, I'll do that then. Thanks again.